# Spring Boot Web application Hosting in Internet

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, web-hosting

I have successfully developed a spring boot web application.i need to deploy this web application in internet.can somebody guide me through the steps ?

Comment: Create a war file and deploy it to tomcat server purchased from any hosting service providers like godaddy,bluehosts ....etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS is as simple as it can be.

1. Create an account using your Credit card (Few debit cards also will work)
2. Login to http://console.aws.amazon.com
3. Click on EC2 (Elastic Compute Cloud). t2.micro instance type is eligible for free tier.
4. Launch instance
5. Generate keypair.
6. Start using your instance using SSH

Make sure to read all documentation related to Costing.

Resources:

[10-Minute Tutorials with Amazon Web Services (AWS)](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/)

Comment: I would even recommend using Elastic Beanstalk instead of "raw" EC2: Beanstalk provides a simple for understanding UI for managing the environment.

Comment: Beanstalk doesn't have a 'free tier' model, you always have to pay a minimum fee per month.